# Can we put an edit text in react-moveable? (Drag and edit both)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, draggable

The text in React Movable box gets dragged on left click and edits on right click with the help of "contentEditable" attribute. But in smartphone, I can't find a way to edit the same, it only gets moved.

```
          <div className="moveable">
            <span
              contentEditable="true"
              onClick={e => {
                this.handleClick(e.nativeEvent);
              }}
            >
              React
              <br />
              Moveable
            </span>
          </div>
```

Please tell me a solution to either allow editing somehow with left clicks or a solution for editable text in smartphone.

This is the CodeSandbox Link for reference:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-moveable-demo-bplv0

Comment: codesandbox has some warnings and does not work at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to scalable, warpable, resizable, target add a state draggable in your code as shown below:

```
 state = {
        target: null,
        container: null,
        scalable: true,
        resizable: false,
        warpable: false,
        draggable: false
      };
 render() {
    const { scalable, warpable, resizable, target, draggable } = this.state;
       return(
          ....your code
             )

      }
```